# Dictionary comprehension with key and value tkinter object

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, list-comprehension

Dictionary comprehension with key and value tkinter object. The tkinter object are pairs of 10 entry widgets.

I want to have

```
dic = {
       ttk.Entry(a_frame, width=20).grid(row=i, column=0):
       ttk.Entry(a_frame, width=20).grid(row=i, column=1)
       for i in range(10)
       }
```

but code above gives

```
dic = {None: None}
```

which I understand as it is a one line tkinter widget construction (as we know we should make two step constraction with assigned variable to avoid it as None object).

I know I can make it the tradidional way by

```
dic = {}
for i in range(10):
    entry1 = ttk.Entry( ...).grid(row=i, column=0)
    entry2 = ttk.Entry( ...).grid(row=i, column=1)
    dic[entry1] = entry2
```

But I want to construct it with dictionary comprehension, to avoid unnecessary declaration ahead of time of dic = {} as I know it is just a dummy as later I put this widget dictionary into another dictionary.

Please help

Comment: Use a function, for example `create_entry(row, col, ...)` to create the entry, grid the entry and return the entry.  Then use `dic = {create_entry(i,0,...): create_entry(i,1,...) for i in range(10)}`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. Yes it creates the dic dictionary, but failed to construct the pair of entry widgets (it only create one entry widget, and it is in error - thus hidden, and only we can see it after we run another correct tkinter window (I use Anaconda 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way of dict-comprehension(Hard to read):

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

a_frame = tk.Tk()
dic = {
    key.grid(row=i, column=0) or key: value.grid(row=i, column=1) or value 
    for i in range(10) 
    for key, value in zip([ttk.Entry(a_frame, width=10)], [ttk.Entry(a_frame, width=10)])
}

print(dic)
a_frame.mainloop()
```

The result of `dic`:

```
{
<tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry>: <tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry2>, 
<tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry3>: <tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry4>, 
<tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry5>: <tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry6>, 
<tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry7>: <tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry8>, 
<tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry9>: <tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry10>, 
<tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry11>: <tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry12>, 
<tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry13>: <tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry14>, 
<tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry15>: <tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry16>, 
<tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry17>: <tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry18>, 
<tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry19>: <tkinter.ttk.Entry object .!entry20>
}
```

Comment: Although this could work,I don't recommend you uset that.

Comment: it works as intended. Your code helps me cut lots of my verbose code lines avoid unnecessary name creations and make the module much easy to read. It also opening my eyes on the usage of 'or' operator, zip function and we can make further statement after the first 'for'. Thank you.

Comment: But responding to your statement above, can you give me reasons why not to use this?

Comment: @KokoEfraim using `zip` and creating a list in the dict-comprehension waste unnecessary overhead.And it is a little hard to read.....